# Connect to existing websocket with Playframework

Tags: java, websocket, playframework-2.3, slack-api

I'm creating a bot for [slack](http://slack.com) and I'm using Play.

I need to connect to an existing websocket with Play.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Can you not use any java websocket client?

Comment: @andHapp i'm currently doing it with Jetty, just wanted to know if there was any way to do it more "Play" style.

Comment: Did you bother reading the docs? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWebSockets

Comment: @sebster I think you didn't pay attention to the question. In what part of the docs do they explain how to connect to an existing websocket? They only explain how to create one.

Comment: @arielgpe You are right. I'm sorry for my passive-aggressive comment.

Comment: Hope this helps: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/c3OFjWwiCGM

Comment: @sebster seems to be what i was looking for, its in scala but i think i can handle it. Thanks!